# How to replace tags with a javascript function from beginning to end?

Tags: javascript, tags, bbcode

Here is my problem, while using the replace javascript function in order to replace html tags with BBcode tags, I encountered this issue:

What I wanted:

```
[b]Some text[/b], with some [b]other text[/b].
```

What I've got:

```
[b]Some text</b>, with some <b>other text[/b].
```

This is basically the way I wrote this:

```
mystring.replace(new RegExp('<b>(.*)</b>','gi'),'[b]$1[/b]');
```

I know that with that example I could simply replace it this way:

```
mystring.replace('<b>','[b]').replace('</b>','[/b]');
```

But the thing is that I want to use it with some divs with a specific ID... If I were to do this by replacing opening and ending tags separately, then I wouldn't be able to replace the '</div>' properly.

Is there a way to have this function run through the string "linearly", from beginning to end, rather than from the extremities towards the center ? (My biggest problem is really that I am not able to formulate this question properly, hence the lack of results while searching the web.)

Thank you for any input you may provide.

Comment: It really depends how far you want to go. As you said, if it is just about parsing simple BBcode you can get away with `str.replace`. If, however, you want to parse a more complex DSL, you will probably have to write your own parser. Could you give an example of the most complex code you would like to parse?

Comment: The code would really not be complex, my only problem is this: If I were to have : `<div id="blue">Text</div> and <div id="green">text</div>` and I wanted to get '[blue]Text[/blue] and [green]text[/green]'. My `</div>` would have to be replace with [/blue] in one place and [/green] in another...

Is there a simple answer to this problem? I may just be lacking experience here, but I don't see one, and it bothers me a bit.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Obligatory [don't do this **link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: So, parsing HTML with a RegExp is a "no-no"?

Comment: Make your browser parse the _HTML_ by adding it to a _Node_, then recurse the node tree to generate your BB-code string.

Comment: Well, Paul, if I understood that correctly, it may very well be a viable solution for my present issue... I guess I will come back and write another question if it doesn't work out. Thanks.

Comment: So, I came up with this. `$l.find('b').prepend('[b]').append('[/b]').replaceWith(function(){return $(this).contents();});` It works, but I'ld like to have your opinion in order to know wether or not I properly understood your suggestion.